# How i can get selected item from ListView?

Tags: java, android

I need to get the selected Item from a ListView in android .

Answer (score 0):

You would use similar code to the following:

```
ListView lv = (ListView)this.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        // Your code goes here.
    }
});
```

Comment: If you don't want a click handler, you can use: lv.getSelectedItem()

Comment: Your answer is for a click, not a selection. Use `setOnItemSelectedListener()` for selection. Your point about `getSelectedItem()` is good, though.

Comment: `getSelectedItem()` always returns `null` for me, even if `setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE)` is set and visual selection is working correctly.